# 'You can expect it!' It's ok?

Tags: word-choice, american-english, informal-language

I told my father that Happy birthday my love father. I have been living in Dublin. But, I will come back to korea in August and I must be celebrated on your next birthday. So, **you can expect it!**

It's grammerically correct? Please let me know if you know anything else. Or you can recommend similar to another phrase:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are writing to your father about returning to Korea to visit him.

> So, you can **expect** it!

is fine, but the more usual phrase (to me) is:

> So, you can **look forward to** it!

meaning looking into the future to that occasion (his next birthday).